# MacVim: How to automatically return to the command line on exit from mvim

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

When I run mvim from OS X's Terminal.app command line, it brings up the GUI version of Vim.  But, when I close the GUI Vim widow (via :q), the window focus is left on the MacVim app (even though there is no open window).  This quite annoying, as it means I have to then refocus to the terminal window I ran the app from so I can continue to use the command line.

This is also different from the default way it works in Windows XP and Linux (at least in Ubuntu & RHEL).

I can see maybe some hack ways of doing this - like changing the mvim script to run vim with the "-f" (foreground) option, and then running some Mac command to refocus the Terminal.  Anyone have a simple way to do this?

Comment: Yes, the simplest solution is to stay in the terminal window: `$ mvim -v filename`.